# How to draw elements from the right to the left?

Tags: android, drawing, android-relativelayout, fill-parent

I want to have a button at the rigth of the screen, and an edittext which take all the place it can take at the left of the button. How can I do?

This xml print me the button at the left of the screen but nothing before :/

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/index_bouton_recherche"
        android:layout_width="45px"
        android:layout_height="45px"
        android:background="@drawable/loupe"
    />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/index_champs_recherche"
        android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/index_bouton_recherche"
    />
```

Comment: add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true" ` to your button and that's it ... with linear layouts you will have to create more layouts for the rest of your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to do this, I use `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` xml attribute.
This XML would solve your problem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/index_champs_recherche"
        android:layout_width ="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1" 
    />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/index_bouton_recherche"
        android:layout_width="45px"
        android:layout_height="45px"
        android:background="@drawable/loupe"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `layout_width="0dp"` means that initially, the view won't require any space. The Button is `wrap_content`, so it only require its space.
The `layout_weight` attribute is applied after, and it shares the remaining space on the layout (the width for orientation=horizontal, height for vertical). Default view weight is 0, so with 1, the EditText will take 100% of the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/index_bouton_recherche"
        android:layout_width="45px"
        android:layout_height="45px"
        android:background="@drawable/loupe"
    />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/index_champs_recherche"
        android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/index_bouton_recherche"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```